# How to remove Bootstrap correctly from Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-mix

I try to start a Laravel 5.4 project without Bootstrap.

After installing Laravel, I edited the following files:

**resources/assets/js/app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');
```

**package.json**

```
...
"devDependencies": {
"axios": "^0.15.3",
"bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
"jquery": "^3.1.1",
"laravel-mix": "^0.7.2",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"vue": "^2.1.10"
},
...
```

I've got the following error:

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
>   error  in ./resources/assets/js/app.js
>
> SyntaxError: /Users/.../package.json: Error while parsing JSON - Unexpected end of JSON input
>       at JSON.parse ()
>   @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly was your edit(s) and what were you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 13):

By default, Laravel 5.4 ships with Bootstrap and Vue.js scaffolding, but not everyone wants to use either of those technologies. With Laravel 5.5 you can run this if you don’t want any scaffolding to be generated out of the box by Laravel:

```
php artisan preset none
```

Answer (score 10):

The line

```
require('./bootstrap')
```

has nothing to do with the Bootstrap CSS library. It loads the bootstrap.js file, which you will find in your assets. This file serves the purpose of "bootstrapping" your application (front-end). If you want to remove the Bootstrap CSS library from your project you should:

- remove it from package.json
- remove dependencies within your app layout
- remove loading of sources from app.js / bootstrap.js

Answer (score 1):

If you run "npm install" in the command line, bootstrap's sass files will be downloaded. Running "npm uninstall bootstrap-sass" afterwards will get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to get rid of bootstrap css codes in my laravel project. I opened the file

```
  resources/sass/app.scss
```

and simply commented out the corresponding line as bellow

```
 // Bootstrap
 //@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```